# Android - string.equals() not working properly

Tags: android

so I am having an issue with .equals for some strange reason, I've used it in the past and its worked great until this one time. So basically what my method is doing is extracting a zip file, scanning the folder for a specific folder name. Heres what it looks like:

```
 public void scanFolder(File src){
        File[] files = src.listFiles(new FileFilter(){

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                if(pathname.isDirectory()){
                    String name = new String(pathname.getName());
                    Toast.makeText(AndroidFileBrowserExampleActivity.this,  
                      name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if(name.equals("assets")){ //problem is here
                        String path =  
                         pathname.toString().replace("assets",  ""); 
                        File src = new File(path);
                        File dest = new File("/sdcard/.MCPE Texture    
                           Installer/0.10.5/");
                        try {
                            zip(src, dest);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }else{
                        scanFolder(pathname);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

        });
    }
```

So even though the folder name is assets, when I use name.equals(assets) it never matches and continues the loop. But whats strange is I tested this out in another method and I created the files on the device manually and it worked fine, here is that method:

```
public void scanFolder(File src){
        File[] files = src.listFiles(new FileFilter(){

            @Override
            public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                if(pathname.isDirectory()){
                    String name = pathname.getName();
                    if(name.equals("assets")){
                        String path = pathname.toString().replace("assets", 
""); 
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, path, 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        scanFolder(pathname);
                    }
                }
                return pathname.isDirectory();
            }

        });
    }
```

I am very confused by this, so if someone could tell me what I am doing wrong that would be great! Thanks!

EDIT:
Heres the debug log that has to do with the scanFolder method:

```
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/.MCPE Texture Installer/0.10.5: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at com.dogger20011.mcpetextureinstaller.AndroidFileBrowserExampleActivity.zip(AndroidFileBrowserExampleActivity.java:546)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at com.dogger20011.mcpetextureinstaller.AndroidFileBrowserExampleActivity$1.accept(AndroidFileBrowserExampleActivity.java:629)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at java.io.File.listFiles(File.java:830)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at com.dogger20011.mcpetextureinstaller.AndroidFileBrowserExampleActivity.scanFolder(AndroidFileBrowserExampleActivity.java:617)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at com.dogger20011.mcpetextureinstaller.AndroidFileBrowserExampleActivity$1.accept(AndroidFileBrowserExampleActivity.java:635)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at java.io.File.listFiles(File.java:830)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at com.dogger20011.mcpetextureinstaller.AndroidFileBrowserExampleActivity.scanFolder(AndroidFileBrowserExampleActivity.java:617)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at com.dogger20011.mcpetextureinstaller.AndroidFileBrowserExampleActivity$1.accept(AndroidFileBrowserExampleActivity.java:635)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at java.io.File.listFiles(File.java:830)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at com.dogger20011.mcpetextureinstaller.AndroidFileBrowserExampleActivity.scanFolder(AndroidFileBrowserExampleActivity.java:617)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at com.dogger20011.mcpetextureinstaller.AndroidFileBrowserExampleActivity.onActivityResult(AndroidFileBrowserExampleActivity.java:150)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3361)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3408)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at 

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
(ZygoteInit.java:827)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052): Caused by: 
libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native 
Method)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at  
libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    at 
libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
04-13 19:20:56.113: W/System.err(11052):    ... 26 more
```

Comment: did you run it through the debugger with a break point on the name.equal line of code and see what is in name or if it is being executed.

Comment: Sir,try this and see `equalsIgnoreCase(string)` also clean your project

Comment: I just added my logcat to the original post, nothing looks out of the ordinary to me. Also, I tried the equalsIgnoreCase and still, no luck. Thanks though.

Comment: use the logger to output name, then you can see what name is actually set to.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with String comparison, rather your log indicates that you are trying to write data to a directory rather than to a file *within* a directory.

Comment: the file you are writing does not exist ...